# how to include parameters in label of Jmeter summary report

Tags: jmeter

I can successfully create a summary report in jmeter but in the label column i need the full get request along with parameters passed.I am not getting the parameters passed in the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it automatically populated with the help of [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) scripting.

Example:

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of HTTP Request
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.PropertyIterator;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;

   HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = (HTTPSamplerProxy) ctx.getCurrentSampler();
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append(sampler.getUrl());
   Arguments args = sampler.getArguments();

   PropertyIterator iter = args.iterator();

   while (iter.hasNext()) {        
         builder.append (iter.next().getStringValue());          
   }

   prev.setSampleLabel(builder.toString());
   ```
3. Run your test.

The code fetches URL and all parameters along with their values and updates parent sampler name with these values:

[image: Sampler Name Change Demo]

As you can see `HTTP Request` became `http://example.com/foo=bar`

You can place the PostProcessor at the same level as HTTP Request samplers to avoid copy-pasting it multiple times or use i.e. [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) or [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) instead.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on using scripting in JMeter and to learn what all these things like `ctx` and `prev` mean.